# how to use pyshortcuts.make_shortcut() to set script run in a conda environment?

Tags: python, icons, shortcut, desktop

dear all:

I am using pyshortcuts to programmatically generate a desktop shortcut for my py files which in turn calls pyc files generated for various python versions.
Somehow, according to the documentation, I have not found a way to set the conda environment that I programmatically created for the pyc files.
Any comments and suggestions will be appreciated.